# Loopback filter like case insensitive

Tags: angularjs, postgresql, loopback

How to user case insensitive where filter in loopback with postgresql.
I have trued using

```
pattern = new RegExp('.*'+data+'.*', "i")
```

but not working.
My code is

```
searchUsersAppointment(data): void {
    let cpr = /^\d+$/.test(data);
    let pattern = new RegExp('.*'+data+'.*', "i");
    let query = {};
    if(cpr){
        query = {where: {CPR: {like: data} } };
    }else{
        query = {where: {firstName: {like: pattern} } };
    }
    this.patientDetailsApi.find(query).subscribe(searchDetails => {
        this.searchDetails = searchDetails;
    })
}
```

Can any one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @RahulSingh I got solution changed **query = {where: {firstName: {like: pattern} } };** to **query = {where: {firstName: {regexp: data+"/i"} } };**

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `Regex` for case insensitive search in Loopback.

If you are using database that support ANSI SQL formats like MySql, PostgreSql you can use the following code snippet:

```
filter.where = {
  name: { 
    ilike: '%'+ search_string +'%'
  }
};
```

If you are using noSQL database like MongoDb use the following code snippet:

```
where = {
  name: {
    like: search_string,
    options: "i" 
  }
};
```

Comment: if i want to have search query on two feilds at time how can i do that ?
like: fisrtName,lastName, middleName @Nahid

Comment: You can use OR operator in where clause to combine the the search filter.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a day fiddling around with it since most answers seem to work for other specific connections.

Here's what worked for me:

Datasource: **loopback-connector-oracle**

```
where: { 
   property: { regexp: `/^${query}/i` }
}
```

**REST API:**

`?filter={"where":{"userName":{"regexp":"/^query/i"}}}`

This does the following validation

```
let str = 'john_smith'
console.log(/^john_smith/i.test(str)) //true
console.log(/^joHN_Smith/i.test(str)) //true
console.log(/^ohn_Smith/i.test(str2)) //false
console.log(/^John_mith/i.test(str2)) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using noSQL database like MongoDb with loopback4 use the following code snippet:

```
const pattern = new RegExp('^' + request.search + '.*', "i");
where: { 
   name: { regexp: pattern }
}
```