# react-admin ReferenceInput and Autocomplete not showing result as I type in

Tags: filter, autocomplete, react-admin

I'm enjoying using react-admin and how promising this frontend seems to be for some dashboard development,

I followed a tutorial react-admin + loopback 4 and trying to filter a long list using a ReferenceInput + Autosuggestion as mentioned here

the list of department show properly in the dropdown list and if I select an item the list gets filtered as it should, however if I type in, the results is an empty dropdown with "No Option" as a result.

Do I have to populate the list somewhere before passing it? or am I missing something? Below is an example of a machine list that I try to filter by department.

Thanks a lot

[image: the dropdown list show MOD4, the filter works if I click on it]

[image: the dropdown list becomes empty if I type in the word MOD]

```
const machineFilters = [
  <ReferenceInput
    source='department_id'
    reference='departments'
    alwaysOn={true}
  >
    <AutocompleteInput />
  </ReferenceInput>,
  
];
```

If I manually enter some choices (I tried with one only) the typing in seems to work, although I thought I wouldn't need to provide the choice according to the   doc of RA

> Tip: If you want to populate the choices attribute with a list of
> related records, you should decorate  with
> , and leave the choices empty

EDIT:

i'm using loopback4, in postman i query this address

`http://localhost:3000/categories?filter={"where": {"description": {  "like": "marking","options": "i"}}}`

in my RA I used

```
const filterToQuery = (searchText) => ({
  where: { description: `${searchText}` },
});


const machineFilters = [

  <ReferenceInput
    source='category_id'
    reference='categories'
    alwaysOn={true}
    sort={{ field: 'code', order: 'ASC' }}
  >
    <AutocompleteInput
      style={{ width: '300px' }}
      source='categories'
      filterToQuery={filterToQuery}
    />
  </ReferenceInput>,
];
```

but still no luck so far, I'm continuing investigating the doc of RA and LB4, any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to tweak the `<AutocompleteInput filterToQuery>` prop so that the string entered by users is turned into the filter you want. Something like that:

```
<AutocompleteInput filterToQuery={string => ({ name_ilike: `%${string}%` })} />
```

This prop is documented here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AutocompleteInput.html#properties

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the link provided by François Zaninotto and some digging here and there, I came up with this, I think there is still some issues I need to fix (the clear button of the AutocomleteInput doesn't give me back the full list of options after typing and deleting the text I entered manually but that's ok for me now.
I still have no idea why I ad to remove the"where" in my query though...

```
const filterToQuery = (searchText) => ({
  description: { like: searchText, options: 'i' },
});

const machineFilters = [
  <ReferenceInput
    source='category_id'
    reference='categories'
    alwaysOn={true}
    sort={{ field: 'code', order: 'ASC' }}
  >
    <AutocompleteInput
      style={{ width: '300px' }}
      source='categories'
      filterToQuery={filterToQuery}
      emptyValue={''}
    />
  </ReferenceInput>,
];
```

some links that helped me:
[Loopback filter like case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536322/loopback-filter-like-case-insensitive)
[Loopback docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Where-filter.html#regular-expressions)